# Nuget package would install before I reinstalled windows but now it will not

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

I am trying to install the NuGet package [Xamarin.Firebase.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/) and every time I do I get an error saying

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 42.1001.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The catch is that about a week ago I was working on this same project and had the package installed with no problems. Then my laptop's install of windows was corrupted and I had to reinstall. I lost that day's work and now the package gives the aforementioned error. I can't find anything else that has changed, any ideas?

Comment: `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth` 42.xxx targets the `MonoAndroid 7.0` framework, either update your project from `MonoAndroid 6.0` to `7.0`, or install an older Firebase Auth package (i.e. `32.x`)

Comment: @SushiHangover Updating to 7.0 would mean supporting only 2.8% of androids which means it is not an option and I tried to install a previous version but it requires older versions of other DLLs that I can't downgrade due to other dependencies. But none of that is to the point because this version of this package installed on this project just fine a week ago.

Comment: ? Updating to 7.0 does not mean you have to ***only*** support API 7.0 devices, your project currently targets the MonoAndroid 6.0 framework and that does not mean you can only run on API 6.0. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/

Comment: @SushiHangover Oh. Okay. That makes me feel dumb. Thanks